# Ruby Thread Pool theory

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

I'm running a Ruby thread pool (`Thread.pool(10)` for example), and I'm running into trouble with how I should actually be handling the logic behind distributing tasks.

I want to run ten tasks at a time, which would normally work - however, `pool.process{...]` doesn't block the main thread after 10 threads are in use - it keeps loading up tasks (so my `while` loop is loading an insane amount of tasks into the pool, which isn't correct... I actually need to check to see if any of the ten tasks return a 'false' before loading more). So, simply put, I want to run ten tasks at a time *and* only load new tasks onto the pool if there's less than ten tasks running.

Should I not be using a pool for this?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this a lot, I ended up having to restructure my code to better fit the logic of what I was doing. There are interesting functions for Thread.pool, such as trim, but the descriptions online didn't quite make enough sense to me to use them.

In short: pool.process should only be run once you've already checked that you want that subtask run.